How do I query System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonArray by value in .net core c#
I wanna query an System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonArray by   prop value  ,
Is there any JsonArray function can query JsonObject in which array index without foreach/forloop or extra libray ?
[    
{"key": 1,"value": "UOB" ,"connections":["WebPOS_dropdownlist","WebIMS_dropdownlist"] ,"synced":0,"last_synced":"2024/7/16 4:26:34"},   
{"key": 2,"value": "OCBC","connections":[],"synced":1,"last_synced":"2024/7/16 4:26:34" }
]

JsonArray arr= (JsonArray)JsonObject.Parse("[    \r\n{\"key\": 1,\"value\": \"UOB\" ,\"connections\":[\"WebPOS_dropdownlist\",\"WebIMS_dropdownlist\"] ,\"synced\":0,\"last_synced\":\"2024/7/16 4:26:34\"},   \r\n{\"key\": 2,\"value\": \"OCBC\",\"connections\":[],\"synced\":1,\"last_synced\":\"2024/7/16 4:26:34\" }\r\n]");

//arr.Where?arr.Select?


//query condition "value" =="OCBC"
[    
{"key": 1,"value": "UOB" ,"connections":["WebPOS_dropdownlist","WebIMS_dropdownlist"] ,"synced":0,"last_synced":"2024/7/16 4:26:34"},   
{"key": 2,"value": "OCBC","connections":[],"synced":1,"last_synced":"2024/7/16 4:26:34" }
]

//expect return filtered jsonarray 
[    
{"key": 1,"value": "UOB" ,"connections":["WebPOS_dropdownlist","WebIMS_dropdownlist"}
]
//or match index 
1



I would guess, that LINQ ".Where", should be possible here.

Why deserialize to a JsonArray instead of proper objects? You'd be able to write items.Where(it=>it.Value=="OCBC"). BTW the format of last_synced is a strong smell. The standard way to represent dates in JSON is ISO8601

The easiest option would be to deserialize to concrete types and use LINQ to find what you want. There's no benefit to deserializing into JsonObject or JsonArray :
public record Item(int key, string value, List<string> connections, 
                   int synced, string last_synced);

...
var items=JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Item>>(jsonString);       
var theItem=items.First(it=>it.value=="OCBC");

foreach(var connection in theItem.connections)
{
    Console.WriteLine(connection);
}
Console.WriteLine(theItem.synced);

If you want to work with JsonArray, you can use LINQ to check specific values. There are no performance gains. You're deserializing to a different type that's meant for JSON manipulation
JsonArray jsonArray = (JsonArray)JsonNode.Parse(jsonString);
var theItem = jsonArray.First(it => it["value"].ToString() == "OCBC");

if (theItem["connections"] is JsonArray connections)
{
    foreach(var connection in connections)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(connection);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(theItem["synced"]);


it works ,thanks a a lot, BTW , if jsonArray matches more than 1 records, how to retrive each record?

Same as any array - use an index or LINQ. First is a LINQ operator that returns the first item.  You can write jsonArray[2] to get the second item or jsonArray.Where(it=>it["value"].ToString() == "OCBC").
